# Add space between a group o radio button

Tags: html

I have a group of radiobutton,
Now how can i add space between a group o radio button's options.
like this

http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3955/radiod.jpg

either using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Discodancer* provided a valiad answer, but note that **IE6** does not support attribute selector (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and you don't need a hack to overcome this problem by applying class to your radio buttons

So your HTML would be:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" class="bar" value="lorem"> Lorem <br>
<input type="radio" name="foo" class="bar" value="ipsum"> Ipsum <br>
<input type="radio" name="foo" class="bar" value="dolor"> Dolor
```

And CSS can be like:

```
input.bar { margin: 5px 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your stylesheet:

```
input[type=radio] { margin-bottom: 15px }
```

Of course, you can increase the 15px to as much as you like.

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` is probably your best choice

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="radios">
    <label><input type="radio"> Foo</label>
    <label><input type="radio"> Bar</label>
</p>

.radios label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Easy peasy and should work in all browsers. Always use `label` for all form elements, especially radio buttons and check boxes, that makes it possible to click the text as well as the tiny button to select the option.